# Love Experiences? Like Bonuses? Are these question fragments correct grammatically?

Tags: questions, sentence-patterns, style-manuals

Or are they a product of digitalization of writing, where we shorten everything?! 
"Love Experiences?" "Like Bonuses? Get more Rewards and Discounts" ...can one use these statements in writing or would it be considered grammatically incorrect?

Comment: It's not necessarily not grammatical, but with no context, it pretty much has no (unambiguous) meaning. It could be part of "_(Do you) love (new) experiences?... come to World of Experiences_" (along the lines of "_Love Ice-cream? ... come to Ben & Jerry's_"). It could mean "_(What are your) love experiences?_" (with whom have you had a relationship). And possibly other uses I've not thought of.

Comment: Voting to close for lack of context.

Answer (score 1):

As a matter of fact, you can see this kind of syntax/wording quite often. That's informal but can be used and is used quite a lot on websites, leaflets and so forth. Just think of "got it" (cookies notification bar), "will do"...etc The subject is always implicit. We all know it's not formal but it's used on a daily basis. As a rule of thumb, I'd say the English language is rather flexible about this sort of thing.